# python3 multiprocessing with huge file loop dosnt load all the lines

Tags: python-3.x, multiprocessing

i am new with python ,  trying to loop huge file with python using multiprocessing  module but i discovered that there is  a limit of size ,when i use 1 core with file contain 8000 line the script stop after 3000 line , and with 2 core just 1500 and with 4 core 1000 line

```
import requests
import sys
import functools
import os
import multiprocessing as mp


count= 0
start = time.time()
file_ip = "url10.txt"
file = open(file_ip, 'r')
urls = file.read().split('\n')

def multi():
p = Pool(processes=8)
result = p.map(fonction, urls)
```

Comment: So, instead of trying to read to whole file into memory at once (with `f.read()`). Try to read and process each line separately with a loop over all the lines. This can be done by `for line in f.readlines():` or with the short cut `for line in f:`

Comment: yes i did that but it is so slow so i am trying to speedup the process

Answer (score 1):

From the [multiprocessing programming guidelines](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing-programming):

> As far as possible one should try to avoid shifting large amounts of data between processes.

The `multiprocessing.Pool` relies on a `pipe` for distributing the work to the children processes. If you fill up that pipe, there are high chances the whole application will end up hanging.

Just try using [`imap`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process#multiprocessing.pool.Pool.imap) instead of `map`. In place of the iterable pass the file object, the logic should read those lines lazily avoiding stuffing the internal buffer.

Comment: what about if i split my huge text file to smaller parts ,, or creating smal list of jobs*

Comment: Also, or you could split it in offsets and send the offsets to the workers. Each worker would open the file independently and `seek` to the offset. In this way you leverage IO concurrency as well. It should be faster as long as you pick the right offsets. Use the `\n` char to calculate the chunk offsets for example.

Comment: yep , it look gr8 idea , even it will took long time for m to do it XD

Comment: i figure-out the problem is in my thread counter show only 444 test from 1000 but in reality all the lines are passed correctly , many threads start at the same time thats why they are not counted XD Daym !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you are calling the multi() function? is this file a simplification of your original?

Comment: yes i must call the function multi() XD its just snipped code

Answer (score 0):

i figure-out the problem is in my thread counter show only 444 test from 1000 but in reality all the lines are passed correctly , many threads start at the same time thats why they are not counted XD Daym !!!!!